# How do I pass a true or false value from a javascript to an ASP.NET server side (code behind)?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

```
        function confirmSubmit() {
            if (confirm("Are you sure you want to proceed?")) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

I have this javascript function above that alerts the user upon clicking on a button.  Now how do I pass a value to the code behind if the user clicks ok or cancel?

I wanted to have something like this:

```
if (user == user1)
{
    updateDataOne();
}
else
{
   if (userX clicks ok/yes over at the javascript dialogue)
   {
       updateDataTwo();
   }
   else
   {
       txtName.Text = "";
   }
}
```

This is what i have for my asp button

```
<asp:Button ID="btnPhaseOne" class="buttonPhases" runat="server" Text="Submit" 
            ValidationGroup="validatePhaseOne" onclick="btnPhaseOne_Click" />
```

Comment: I believe this has been asked a lot of times...

Comment: you need to use hidden field for it

Answer (score 0):

Use hidden field.Assign value to hidden field.now  returning true from JavaScript function will cause postpack. On the server side check the value of the hidden field & based on that the decision.